# Elixir long running background task doesn't complete, sometimes crashes

Tags: ffmpeg, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, erlang-otp

As a little bit of background, I have an endpoint that is responsible for video upload. What I want to do, is copy the video file to a temporary location from the request, and spin up an asynchronous task (ffmpeg shell process) to transcode that video in the background so that my endpoint can return a 200 in a timely manner, and the response does not wait for ffmpeg to finish transcoding that video.

Here is my code from the controller.

```
def create(conn, %{"file" => file ... })
    uuid = Video.uuid()
    tmp_path = Application.get_env(:myapp, :video_tmp_path) <> "/" <> uuid
    :ok = File.cp(file.path, tmp_path)
    VideoService.process(tmp_path, final_path)
```

The inside of VideoService looks like the following.

```
defmodule MyApp.Services do
  defmodule VideoService do
    def process(tmp_path, final_path) do
      Task.start_link fn ->
        System.cmd("ffmpeg", ["-i", tmp_path, final_path, "-hide_banner"])
        File.rm(tmp_path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem I am having here is that no matter what, nothing past the `System.cmd("ffmpeg")` call executes in the `VideoService`, and sometimes the `System.cmd` call doesn't even spin up an `ffmpeg` process. Am I doing something wrong here? What I need is a way to spin this `ffmpeg` shell process out in the background from the controller / service and respond with a 200 on video upload. Thanks for help in advance. I am new to elixir / OTP, so I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.

I also randomly see the following error

`erl_child_setup: failed with error 32 on line 240`

Comment: _Sidenote:_ when the server accepts the request, but the processing is not finished yet, the server must respond with [**202 Accepted**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) rather than with **200 OK**.

Comment: Start with spitting the outcome from `System.cmd/2` out to the log for the further investigation: `IO.inspect(System.cmd(...))`. Another question would be: have you examined your Phoenix log? Does it contain anything related?

Comment: I am not sure about where exactly you call this `process` from, but please be aware `Task.start_link/1` is **linked to the parent process** and as soon as the parent dies, it dies as well. The possible solution would be to have **a dedicated `GenServer` in your supervision tree, that will spawn tasks**. That way you’ll be sure the parent process is always alive.

Comment: Try starting an instance of `Task.Supervisor` in your app's supervisor and then use `Task.Supervisor.start_child` to start the Task. This should solve what @mudasobwa pointed out.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, and let you both know what happens. Thanks for the suggestions and instruction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help from mudasobwa and Dogbert to answer this question. I followed [this guide](http://phoenixframework.org/blog/task-supervisor) to get an independent supervisor up and running in my phoenix stack like they suggested. The gist of this is to add a line to `lib/myapp.ex` that creates a Supervisor like such

`supervisor(Task.Supervisor, [[name: MyApp.TaskSupervisor]])`

Then when you want to run a task with that supervisor as the parent, you can run

`Task.Supervisor.start_child(MyApp.TaskSupervisor, fn -> do_stuff() end)`

In my case, do_stuff involved spawning an ffmpeg process and doing some file cleanup. The basic idea here is that you are doing this work with the Supervisor as parent so that even when the request exits and that process dies, your supervisor is still alive and well since it is always up when your application is up.